# Is it possible to get_terms by author?

Tags: author, terms

I get terms from all my posts with `get_terms`,

```
$tags = get_terms( 'mytags', '&number=5&orderby=date&order=desc&hide_empty=1' );
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/tags/'.$tag->slug.'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
}
```

Is it possible to get_terms included to the posts made by author?
I try to add a list with all the terms (tags) in author.php template,

thanks a lot!

Comment: Terms aren't specific to author, they're specific to post types or posts, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, because terms are assigned to posts, not authors.

You will need to query all posts, get their terms and authors, and then filter out terms which came with posts that have other authors than `get_query_var('author')`.

Note that depending on the number of posts your site has, this kind of query could be very expensive. A better way would be to either record term IDs inside an user meta key during `save_post` (still kind of slow), or create your own table with the data you need (fast).

Comment: Possibly I think it's better to query posts under the author - instead of ALL posts. That's probably going to cause some performance issues there. When you have posts from the other, you can then continue the same process.